# Translation matrix for multiple spins

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, quantum-spin

I need to do a translation, but not a translation in the classical definition, I need to, in a system with a operator, for example, $$ \sigma^z_j=1\otimes \cdots \otimes 1\otimes \sigma^z\otimes 1 \otimes \cdots$$

An operator that allow us to translate this spin with the next space,$$\sigma_j \rightarrow \sigma_{j+1}$$

I have not much experience working with this tensor product and I dont know if there is a way to construct this operator

Comment: Just to be clear, do you want an operator $U$ such that $U\sigma_j^z=\sigma_{j+1}^z$?

Comment: Yes!, I have not especify this, but, with how work the operators, I don't know if other possibility to construct it is $U^{\dagger}\sigma^z_jU=\sigma_{j+1}^z$ or similar...